# Radio button - edit

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I have a create-account form that has a line like this:

```
<li>
   <label>Question1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="name1" value="yes">Yes
   <input type="radio" name="name1" value="no">No
</li>
```

After the account is set, the user can edit the account info. In the edit-account form, how could I display the radio buttons with the initially selected value? I have the value and I want the respective button to be checked when the form is opened.

Thank you.

Cheers

Comment: Which programming language you preffer JS, PHP?

Comment: Set the checked value to checked <input type="radio" name="somename" checked="checked" value="yes">

Comment: How u get the initial value?

Comment: What you need exactly ?

Comment: @DarkBee I did this: device: $('#' + id + 'input:radio[name="name1"]:checked').val()

Comment: I'm not following. U have user Bob who selects `no`, Bob then submits/saves and leaves the site. Then Bob returns and re-opens the form and he needs to see that `no` is selected ?

Comment: <input type="radio" name="name1" value="yes" checked="checked"  That should work!>

Comment: @DarkBee When Bob returns he has to be able to change his initial answer. But his initial answer must be displayed (the button checked) before he changes it (if so he chooses)

Comment: Then u will need to store Bob his answer. Lets say in a database/cookie otherwise u can't know what Bob selected.

Comment: @DarkBee I have all the information stored in a database and I'm using jQuery and PHP to manipulate it.

Comment: If u don't use a template engine then u can do something like : `<input type="radio" name="name1" <?php if ($res['name1'] == true) echo 'checked';?> />Yes`

Comment: @DarkBee This is the way I'll do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can add checked="checked" to the default answer (see below)

```
<li>
   <label>Question1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="name1" checked="checked" value="yes">Yes
   <input type="radio" name="name1" value="no">No
</li>
```

Comment: note that in non-xhtml u can use `<input type="radio" name="name1" checked value="yes">Yes`

Comment: Yes, I know.
But I normally use checked="checked" :)

Comment: I know you can write also this :)
But it's the default to use this checked or checked="checked" as soon the attribute is set

Comment: @WesleyMurch, it's funny but `checked="no"` and `checked="unchecked"` [work the same way](http://jsfiddle.net/ZMLYw/) as your variation:). So boolean attributes work.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn exactly what I meant to demonstrate. Just a side note really. Any non-empty string works.

Answer (score 2):

If 2nd required to be checked

```
<li>
   <label>Question1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="name1" value="yes">Yes
   <input type="radio" name="name1" value="no" checked>No
</li>
```

if 1st required to be checked.

```
<li>
   <label>Question1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="name1" value="yes" checked>Yes
   <input type="radio" name="name1" value="no"> No
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the initial value in java script then you need to write the the java script code for that.

```
<li>
   <label>Question1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="name1" value="yes" checked="checked">Yes
   <input type="radio" name="name1" value="no">No
</li>
```

//Try this inside the java script

```
var valuee=document.getElementByName("name1").value;
```

OR

If you need the value in servlet or server side , when you submit the button , then you use 
request parameter for getting that value.

```
//In Servlet
    String valuee=request.getParameter("name1");
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify your server side language. For example for ruby and erb, when you have a model `Account`, method `question1` will get an answer "yes" or "no":

```
<li>
   <label>Question1</label>
   <input type="radio" name="name1" value="yes" <%= "checked" if @account.question1 == "yes" %>>Yes
   <input type="radio" name="name1" value="no" <%= "checked" if @account.question1 == "no" %>>No
</li>
```

When server renders this page, it checks an answer and renders `checked` for the corresponding elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="radio" name="name1" value="yes" checked="checked">Yes
```

or

```
<input type="radio" name="name1" value="no" checked="checked">NO
```

Use this value of checked="checked" where ever you want to display the default checked mark

Answer (score 0):

use an attribute `Selected="selected"`

thats all